# How To Pass Data From View To View In Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a controller **main.php**. From this controller am loading the view and passing data.

```
  $this->load->view('main',$data);
```

In my main view am loading the following:

```
 $this->load->view('header');
 $this->load->view('content',$newData);
 $this->load->view('footer')
```

But when I tried to access `$newData`, I am getting it as not set.

```
$data is of type
    Array
  (
      [newData] => Array
      (
        [0] => abc
        [1] => cde
        [2] => pqr
        [3] => xyz
    )
   )
```

How can I access the new data in my content view?

Comment: In your second code clause (i.e. the `this->load->(...`) should throw a syntax error. Are you getting that?

Comment: yea . actually its my typing mistake. i'll change it

Comment: I don't know CI, but suspect you can only load one view. Perhaps, load your content view, and from there, render header and footer partials? There should be a view helper to do that, and to pass your variable to the partials if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

looking at the structure of `$data`, you may try this, not tested:

```
$this->load->view('main',$data);
```

in main view:

```
$this->load->view('header');
$this->load->view('content', array('newData' => $newData));
$this->load->view('footer')
```

When you try to access the `newData`, the view expect there is a key Called `newData`, but what you passed in is the `newData` itself, so if you wrapped it with array, then it should be fine.

Comment: this is the correct answer... but it would be array('newData' => $newData)

Answer (score 1):

```
 $this->load->('content',$newData);
```

instead it user

```
$this->load->view('content');
```

not $data array will be accessible in content view..
Codeigniter have a nice documentation..

Answer (score -1):

1st `$this->load->('header');` is not a valid php line!

because there is no function name `$this->load->FUNCTION_NAME('')`!

so it will give u an error.

2nd **you cannot load views from inside another view**, loading views is the job of the controller.

if you need more information regarding MVC programming please let me know :)